# error in compiling cilk plus with gcc-4.7

Tags: gcc, cilk, cilk-plus

I get the following error

```
main.c:107:2: internal compiler error: in extract_for_fields, at cilk-spawn.c:1857
}
```

and the relevant lines are:

```
cilk_for (index = 0; table_name[index]!=NULL; ++index )
{
      /* some work*/
}
```

`Line 107` corresponds to the closing braces of cilk_for loop.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: That's a compiler bug. Does it work in 4.6? Are you using some pre-release of 4.7?

Comment: no. cilk plus can only be build with `gcc-4.7` as intel has added that branch to `gcc-4.7` only. So is there nothing I can do about it except sending the a bug report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did above was not a valid `cilk_for` loop because the `cilk_for` loop must test the control variable. Also one must be able to predict how many time the loop will run and in this case this is not possible. So the correct version for this will be

```
int count=0;
while(table_name[count]!=NULL)
    count++;
cilk_for (index = 0; index!=count; ++index )
{
      /* some work*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try building with no optimization (omit any optimization flags, or use `-O0` explicitely).

If that helps, you can try and see if `-O1` (some optimization) works, then `-O2`, and so on. 
If you're lucky, you can figure out that way which optimization is causing the problem, and then simply disable that optimization with some `-fno-foo` flag.

Comment: I got the fix and posted it above.